# Separate digits using Python

Tags: python, digits

I'm looking for an elegant way to separate numbers in a single digits

For example `20` to be `2, 0`

The way that I found is using a list comprehension:
`[int(num) for num in str(number)]`

Is there another way to do that?

Comment: There are many ways. What's the issue with your way?

Comment: @yatu that is not equivalent. `list(map(int, str(number)))` would be.

Comment: True didn't see the casting to int part @L3viathan

Comment: try: `", ".join(list(str(number)))` if you want a string with comma separated numbers, or `[*map(int,str(number))]` if you want a list of one digit integers

Comment: I mean is not a problem with this approach, but since python has a lot of math powerful tools, maybe we have a best alternative to do that

Answer (score 2):

a math solution (this only works with positive numbers as is):

```py
import math

def get_digits(n):                                                              

    if n == 0:                                                                  
        return [0]                                                              

    digits = []
    while n:
        digits.append(n % 10)
        n = n // 10                                                                                

    return list(reversed(digits))   

for n in [0, 1, 10, 235, 5555]:                                                 
    print(n, get_digits(n))
```

output

```
0 [0]
1 [1]
10 [1, 0]
235 [2, 3, 5]
5555 [5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
num = 20
digits = []
for x in range(0,len(str(num))):
    digits.append(int(str(num)[x]))

print(digits)
```

Comment: It's actually worse option than what OP proposed.

Comment: using a list comprehension is more clear, anyway thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
digits_list = list(str(num))
```